# Como volver al anterior uinavigationcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, xcode

Me gustaría saber si hay manera de volver al anterior `UINavigationController` de manera que no tenga que volver a instanciarlo, esto es porque quiero pasar una variable al anterior *view controller* y seguidamente irme a él sin necesidad de instanciarlo de nuevo.

La cosa es que el *view controller* actual está dentro de un nuevo `UINavigation`, os dejo el código:

```
let vc:TotalSlidesViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TotalSlidesViewController") as! TotalSlidesViewController
vc.previousVC = self
navigationVC = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: vc)
self.navigationController?.presentViewController(navigationVC, animated: true, completion:nil)
```

Y después cuando quiero volver atrás en el Segundo ViewController:

```
previousVC.itemsCollection.appendContentsOf(slidesAdded)
```

Aquí iría la parte en la que he de volver atrás, si hago un `popToRoot` no funciona ya que ya estoy en el inicio del actual `UINavigationController`.

Answer (score 2):

La respuesta sería:

```
self.navigationController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```